# É possível desenvolver extensões pro Safari usando Windows ou Linux?

Tags: apple, safari

Recordo-me que antigamente existia um Safari pra Windows, o qual não recebe mais atualizações, no entanto mesmo com ele era necessário ter uma licença de desenvolvedor Apple, na época era free pra desenvolver pro safari (acho que ainda é basta acessar https://developer.apple.com/enroll/ e se cadastrar, tem que dar telefone e endereço)

Todavia agora precisamos do *OS X El Capitan* ou *Yosemite* e eu não tenho um Mac.

O que eu gostaria de saber é se é possível desenvolver as extensões usando Windows ou Linux sem precisar de um Mac e sem XCode?

> **Nota:** Eu não pretendo publicar [Safari Extensions Gallery](https://extensions.apple.com), apenas distribuir pra algumas pessoas pra uso pessoal (eu não sei se isso implica em algo com a Apple)

No caso preciso criar um popup ao clicar na extensão semelhante ao do Chrome e injetar alguns códigos em páginas especificas:

```
*://stackapps.com/*
*://askubuntu.com/*
*://superuser.com/*
*://superuser.com/*
*://serverfault.com/*
*://mathoverflow.com/*
*://stackoverflow.com/*
*://stackexchange.com/*
*://*.stackapps.com/*
*://*.askubuntu.com/*
*://*.superuser.com/*
*://*.superuser.com/*
*://*.serverfault.com/*
*://*.mathoverflow.com/*
*://*.stackoverflow.com/*
*://*.stackexchange.com/*
```

Answer (score 0):

Hoje desenvolvemos através do [Construtor de Extensões](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/UsingExtensionBuilder/UsingExtensionBuilder.html) dentro do próprio Safari. É necessário um Mac e uma conta no [Developer Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/) que custa 99 dólares por ano. **Isso significa que não é possível desenvolver utilizando Windows ou Linux.** Afinal, precisamos de um Safari minimamente recente, que só funciona no OS X.

É possível, no entanto, instalar o Mac num PC comum, o que é conhecido como Hackintosh. Apesar de ser tecnicamente possível, essa solução é legalmente problemática – no mínimo, uma violação dos termos de serviço. Apesar disso e de outros problemas, como a compatibilidade com hardware limitada, muitas pessoas desenvolvem aplicativos e inclusive distribuem sem problemas.

Comment: Você começou dizendo **é necessário um Mac**, mas eu perguntei, *tem como fazer no Windows ou Linux?*, poderia editar a resposta? Você afirmou que não tem como sem Mac, mas eu estou pedindo uma solução alternativa apenas e não uma existente. Eu quero apenas desenvolver e não distribuir. Obrigado por entender.

Comment: Necessário é aquilo essencial, indispensável. Se é necessário um mac, e um Windows ou Linux não é mac, isso significa que não é possível fazer no Windows ou Linux. Boa sorte com o hackintosh

Comment: Amigo nem de longe citei Hackintosh, eu citei algo independente, tal como aquele serviço http://crossrider.com, eu entendo a boa vontade da sua resposta, mas isso que você respondeu eu já havia citado no corpo da própria pergunta e título, realmente se não há solução vou esperar ver se aparece alguma solução no futuro, espero que entenda. Obrigado mesmo assim.

Comment: A sua pergunta é "é possível desenvolver extensão pro safari sem mac?", e minha resposta é "não". Acho que você quis perguntar "como desenvolver pra safari sem mac?". Por favor, edite sua pergunta

Comment: Eu ia lhe dar um upvote, mas notei que se ofendeu com algo e deu um downvote simplesmente arbitrário e ainda levou meu comentário a mal sem necessidade. Espero que reveja a sua decisão. Não vejo muita diferença de *É possível desenvolver extensões pro Safari sem um Mac (ou XCode)?* para *como desenvolver pra safari sem mac?*. A pergunta ao meu ver estava bem clara e eu já havia dito que já sabia o que era necessário e que estava procurando algo alternativo, **em nenhum** momento disse que sua resposta era ruim, só disse que não foi o que eu pedi, espero que seja mais compreensivo :)

Comment: Há uma discrepância entre o que foi perguntado e o que você deseja saber. Querer uma "solução alternativa e não uma existente" é um paradoxo por si só (todas as soluções alternativas são existentes). Apesar da pergunta parecer viável, sua intenção expressa nos comentários é de obter uma resposta que não existe sem deixar isso claro. Além disso, antes não era claro se você se referia ao Mac OS ou ao computador Mac. No 1º caso, não há solução; no 2º caso, o Hackintosh é a única solução. Devido a esses problemas, avaliei essa pergunta com downvote.

Comment: Causou-me estranheza você ter dito que ia dar upvote mas decidiu esperar para que eu revisse o meu negativo. Sou contra esse tipo de acordo e defendo a análise imparcial aqui no StackOverflow. Reitero que meu downvote considerou apenas o mérito da questão. Não avalio conduta (coisa subjetiva), apenas o mérito de acordo com as regras e boas convenções do site. Abraços

Comment: pelo seu segundo comentário me pareceu sim que o downvote teve tal motivação, já que foi depois do meu comentário que ocorreu somente depois da sua resposta, ou seja levou a mal sim o que eu disse, deve tentar não levar a mal tudo, frases em texto as vezes soam diferente do que foram falados. Mas tudo bem, esclarecimentos feitos, sua resposta me parece valida, como já disse antes, mas ainda sim não é o que procuro, mas quem sabe se ano que vem melhorar consigo dar entrada em um Mac :) ... [Recomendo que sempre presuma boa intenção](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice).